# Connection error while setting up academic VPN

Tags: vpn, connection

I am trying to set up my university's VPN on my ubuntu so that I can access the university's network from my home. But it always ends up with an error "activation of network connection failed". can anyone please help me out here? on windows I simply have to choose IKEv2 and everything works. On ubuntu I installed the strong swan and all, but when connecting, still the same error.